# Apache Mina SSHD and Jsch: Input stream is always 0

Tags: java, inputstream, jsch, sshd, apache-mina

I am testing simple Apache Mina SSHD server using Jsch library. Junit test looks like:

```
package com.ssh;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.sshd.SshServer;
import org.apache.sshd.common.NamedFactory;
import org.apache.sshd.server.PasswordAuthenticator;
import org.apache.sshd.server.UserAuth;
import org.apache.sshd.server.auth.UserAuthPassword;
import org.apache.sshd.server.keyprovider.SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider;
import org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSession;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.ssh.util.EchoShellFactory;

public class SshServiceTest {

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder testFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    private static final String USERNAME = "username";

    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";

    private static final String HOSTNAME = "localhost";

    private SshServer sshd;

    @Before
    public void prepare() throws IOException {
        setupSSHServer();
    }

    private void setupSSHServer() throws IOException {
        sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
        sshd.setPort(22);
        sshd.setKeyPairProvider(
                new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(testFolder.newFile("hostkey.ser").getAbsolutePath()));

        List<NamedFactory<UserAuth>> userAuthFactories = new ArrayList<NamedFactory<UserAuth>>();
        userAuthFactories.add(new UserAuthPassword.Factory());
        sshd.setUserAuthFactories(userAuthFactories);

        sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(new PasswordAuthenticator() {
            public boolean authenticate(String username, String password, ServerSession session) {
                return USERNAME.equals(username) && PASSWORD.equals(password);
            }
        });

        sshd.setShellFactory(new EchoShellFactory()); 
        sshd.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testConnection() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test started");

        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(USERNAME, HOSTNAME, 22);
        session.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("pwd");

        ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

        channel.connect();

        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0)
                    break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception ee) {
            }
        }

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("DONE");

    }

    @After
    public void cleanup() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            sshd.stop(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And my shell factory looks like:

```
package com.ssh.util;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.InterruptedIOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.sshd.common.Factory;
import org.apache.sshd.server.Command;
import org.apache.sshd.server.Environment;
import org.apache.sshd.server.ExitCallback;

public class EchoShellFactory implements Factory<Command> {

    public Command create() {
        return new EchoShell();
    }

    public static class EchoShell implements Command, Runnable {

        private InputStream in;
        private OutputStream out;
        private OutputStream err;
        private ExitCallback callback;
        private Environment environment;
        private Thread thread;

        public InputStream getIn() {
            return in;
        }

        public OutputStream getOut() {
            return out;
        }

        public OutputStream getErr() {
            return err;
        }

        public Environment getEnvironment() {
            return environment;
        }

        public void setInputStream(InputStream in) {
            this.in = in;
        }

        public void setOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
            this.out = out;
        }

        public void setErrorStream(OutputStream err) {
            this.err = err;
        }

        public void setExitCallback(ExitCallback callback) {
            this.callback = callback;
        }

        public void start(Environment env) throws IOException {
            environment = env;
            thread = new Thread(this, "EchoShell");
            thread.start();
        }

        public void destroy() {
            thread.interrupt();
        }

        public void run() {
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            try {
                for (;;) {
                    String s = r.readLine();
                    if (s == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    out.write(("executed " + s + "\r\n").getBytes());
                    out.flush();
                    if ("exit".equals(s)) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
                // Ignore
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error executing EchoShell...");
            } finally {
                if (r != null) {
                    try {
                        r.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // ignore
                    }
                }
                callback.onExit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case value of in.available() is always "0" and while look runs forever. I have to stop the process manually. When SSHD server is up, I can connect to it through putty and execute dummy commands. Only when I try to connect to this server using Jsch lib, input stream as shown above is always 0. I searched at many places, but couldn't find whats wrong. Please let me know, if you have any idea on how to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Because the "exec" mode is not interactive, the program thinks the execution is not finished. So you need to use the "shell" mode instead of "exec", but you need to add "exit" or "quit" command after your command to end the interaction.